# matlab size function throw an exception

Tags: image, matlab, image-size

I'm trying to get the size of an image in matlab, here is the code:

```
img = imread('folder\image1.jpg');      
size(img);
```

I'm getting this error :

> "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

I dont know why this happens, any help to know the issue would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: If you`re in a script try to provide a variable to your size. Like `mySize = size(img);`

Comment: I tried it, I got the same error

Comment: Did img is not null ? `if(img) s = size(img); end`

Comment: Have you create a function name size ? Type `which size` in MatLab command window. Look like the function didn`t found the good implementation.

Comment: actually, the issue disappear now but it didn't enter into this if condition although when I typed img to check if it is empty or not, it returns me values so I'm still not sure what is wrong here and how it didn't enter this condition

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... which if condition? Isn't the code pasted into the question the one that gets you the error?

Comment: I mean this if(img) s = size(img);

Comment: I got this when I typed which size  :
size is a variable.

Comment: I think the right way to write that would be `if ~isempty(img), s=size(img); end;` and delete from your workspace any variable called `size`.

Comment: I tried something now that might help us find the issue, 
>> a =  [1 1 1;2 2 2]; 
>> size(a)
ans =2     2     2
     1     1     1

Comment: Although I clear the history of my commands but the variable size was not cleared  but finally when I closed matlab and open it again everything is working properly.  Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. And, just to avoid unnecessary Matlab restarts, an easy way to clear your entire workspace is `clear all`, or `clear classes`.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments your error occurs because you overloaded the `size` function with a variable.